# Forcing HTTP on site that previously used HTTPS

Tags: apache, ssl

On a website that has not renewed the SSL certificate, it seems that if someone tries to access the site using https, browsers deliver the "unsafe" warning before the htaccess rewrite rule is activated.

Is there a way to prevent this? The site is on a vps so I have the ability to modify server files.

Comment: I don't really see a way how to do that. and that does make sense from a security point of view. Otherwise users might not realize that the encryption was suddenly silently dropped on your site. The issue is that the first request is sent via https, no matter what you try on the server side. Without a certificate you cannot send a valid response. You can only fully block the https access and _hope_ that users use the http protocol. _Or you simply get a valid and working certificate..._

Comment: Try a reverse proxy like Cloudflare to simulate having an SSL connection